# Import Address Table in Process Hollowing

Tags: pe, injection, process, iat

I know that the PE loader is the one that is responsible for assigning addresses in a PE Import Address Table, so why when we inject code using process hollowing we don't build the IAT?
We just copy all the sections and headers but we don't resolve the addresses in the IAT. I don't understand how it works, does the resolving happens after the injection or something?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you should resolve the address in IAT.

This is a manually mapped dll code, you can take a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <intrin.h>

typedef HMODULE(WINAPI* pLoadLibraryA)(LPCSTR);
typedef FARPROC(WINAPI* pGetProcAddress)(HMODULE, LPCSTR);

typedef BOOL(WINAPI* PDLL_MAIN)(HMODULE, DWORD, PVOID);

typedef struct _MANUAL_INJECT
{
    PVOID ImageBase;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders;
    PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION BaseRelocation;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR ImportDirectory;
    pLoadLibraryA fnLoadLibraryA;
    pGetProcAddress fnGetProcAddress;
}MANUAL_INJECT, * PMANUAL_INJECT;

DWORD WINAPI LoadDll(PVOID p)
{
    PMANUAL_INJECT ManualInject;

    HMODULE hModule;
    INT64 i, Function, count, delta;

    PDWORD ptr;
    PWORD list;

    PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION pIBR;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pIID;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME pIBN;
    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA FirstThunk, OrigFirstThunk;

    PDLL_MAIN EntryPoint;
    VOID (*EntryPointNew)(VOID);

    ManualInject = (PMANUAL_INJECT)p;

    pIBR = ManualInject->BaseRelocation;
    delta = (DWORD)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase - ManualInject->NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase); // Calculate the delta

    // Relocate the image

    while (pIBR->VirtualAddress)
    {
        if (pIBR->SizeOfBlock >= sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION))
        {
            count = (pIBR->SizeOfBlock - sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)) / sizeof(WORD);
            list = (PWORD)(pIBR + 1);

            for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (list[i])
                {
                    ptr = (PDWORD)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase + (pIBR->VirtualAddress + (list[i] & 0xFFF)));
                    *ptr += delta;
                }
            }
        }

        pIBR = (PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)((LPBYTE)pIBR + pIBR->SizeOfBlock);
    }

    pIID = ManualInject->ImportDirectory;

    // Resolve DLL imports

    while (pIID->Characteristics)
    {
        OrigFirstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase + pIID->OriginalFirstThunk);
        FirstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase + pIID->FirstThunk);

        hModule = ManualInject->fnLoadLibraryA((LPCSTR)ManualInject->ImageBase + pIID->Name);

        if (!hModule)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        while (OrigFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData)
        {
            if (OrigFirstThunk->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG)
            {
                // Import by ordinal

                Function = (INT64)ManualInject->fnGetProcAddress(hModule, (LPCSTR)(OrigFirstThunk->u1.Ordinal & 0xFFFF));

                if (!Function)
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }

                FirstThunk->u1.Function = Function;
            }

            else
            {
                // Import by name

                pIBN = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase + OrigFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData);
                Function = (INT64)ManualInject->fnGetProcAddress(hModule, (LPCSTR)pIBN->Name);

                if (!Function)
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }

                FirstThunk->u1.Function = Function;
            }

            OrigFirstThunk++;
            FirstThunk++;
        }

        pIID++;
    }

    if (ManualInject->NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint)
    {
        EntryPoint = (PDLL_MAIN)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase + ManualInject->NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
        EntryPointNew = (VOID(*)(VOID))((INT64)ManualInject->ImageBase + 0x2350);
        __debugbreak();
        //return EntryPoint((HMODULE)ManualInject->ImageBase, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, NULL); // Call the entry point
        EntryPointNew();
    }

    return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI LoadDllEnd()
{
    return 0;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pIDH;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pINH;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pISH;

    HANDLE hProcess, hThread, hFile;
    PVOID buffer, image, mem;
    DWORD i, FileSize, ProcessId, ExitCode, read;

    MANUAL_INJECT ManualInject;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("\nUsage: ManualInject [DLL name] [PID]\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nOpening the DLL.\n");
    hFile = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); // Open the DLL

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to open the DLL (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    FileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, FileSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (!buffer)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to allocate memory for DLL data (%d)\n", GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return -1;
    }

    // Read the DLL

    if (!ReadFile(hFile, buffer, FileSize, &read, NULL))
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to read the DLL (%d)\n", GetLastError());

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        return -1;
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);

    pIDH = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)buffer;

    if (pIDH->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Invalid executable image.\n");

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    pINH = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)buffer + pIDH->e_lfanew);

    if (pINH->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Invalid PE header.\n");

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(pINH->FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_DLL))
    {
        printf("\nError: The image is not DLL.\n");

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    ProcessId = wcstoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    printf("\nOpening target process.\n");
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessId);

    if (!hProcess)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to open target process (%d)\n", GetLastError());

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nAllocating memory for the DLL.\n");
    image = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, pINH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE); // Allocate memory for the DLL

    if (!image)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to allocate memory for the DLL (%d)\n", GetLastError());

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        return -1;
    }

    printf("[*]Remote Dll Base %llx\n", image);

    // Copy the header to target process

    printf("\nCopying headers into target process.\n");

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, image, buffer, pINH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL))
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to copy headers to target process (%d)\n", GetLastError());

        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, image, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    pISH = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(pINH + 1);

    // Copy the DLL to target process

    printf("\nCopying sections to target process.\n");

    for (i = 0; i < pINH->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (PVOID)((LPBYTE)image + pISH[i].VirtualAddress), (PVOID)((LPBYTE)buffer + pISH[i].PointerToRawData), pISH[i].SizeOfRawData, NULL);
    }

    printf("\nAllocating memory for the loader code.\n");
    mem = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, 4096, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE); // Allocate memory for the loader code

    if (!mem)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to allocate memory for the loader code (%d)\n", GetLastError());

        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, image, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&ManualInject, 0, sizeof(MANUAL_INJECT));

    ManualInject.ImageBase = image;
    ManualInject.NtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)image + pIDH->e_lfanew);
    ManualInject.BaseRelocation = (PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)((LPBYTE)image + pINH->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress);
    ManualInject.ImportDirectory = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((LPBYTE)image + pINH->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);
    ManualInject.fnLoadLibraryA = LoadLibraryA;
    ManualInject.fnGetProcAddress = GetProcAddress;

    printf("\nWriting loader code to target process.\n");
    PVOID RemoteLoaderAddr = (PVOID)((PMANUAL_INJECT)mem + 1);

    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, mem, &ManualInject, sizeof(MANUAL_INJECT), NULL); // Write the loader information to target process
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, RemoteLoaderAddr, LoadDll, (DWORD)LoadDllEnd - (DWORD)LoadDll, NULL); // Write the loader code to target process

    printf("[*]Remote Loader %llx\n", RemoteLoaderAddr);
    system("pause");
    printf("\nExecuting loader code.\n");
    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)RemoteLoaderAddr, mem, 0, NULL); // Create a remote thread to execute the loader code

    if (!hThread)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to execute loader code (%d)\n", GetLastError());

        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, image, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &ExitCode);

    if (!ExitCode)
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, image, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

        CloseHandle(hThread);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    CloseHandle(hThread);
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    printf("\nDLL injected at %#x\n", image);

    if (pINH->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint)
    {
        printf("\nDLL entry point: %#x\n", (PVOID)((LPBYTE)image + pINH->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint));
    }

    VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;
}
```